# Dynamic menu from database in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am looking to store my nav links from a standard navigation menu in my database. Ideally, this would allow some specific (non-technical) users the ability to maintain links on the webapp. Today, my nav menu is a 'static' page included into my base.html and is the same across all pages served up. Any changes requires me to manually update the nav static file and re-deploy.

My struggle (and it could be my limited django experience) is how to be able to generate the data and render it from within the base.html/nav include without having to literally generate the menu items on every single rendering of a page (e.g. getting the menu list and sending to all rendering calls). I have dozens of pages so this isn't really an option to do manually.

I've searched for this and it looks like i'm not the only one, but the closest solution is from like 2006 and I'm sure there's been some likely advancements in this area over the past 15 years.

Appreciate any info that can point me in the right direction.
Cheers!

Comment: you can use django template inheritance. here is link.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

If your menu is just an list items you can create one database table that has alteast link **text, address, is_active and order** in which they should align.
So you gotta need to get navitems in each views, or you can make one base view that has get_context_data method overridden.

Your code would look like this.

**models.py**

```
class NavLinks(models.Model):
    title = ...
    address = ...
    order = ...
    is_active = ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["order"]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.base import ContextMixin

class NavView(ContextMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
            context["nav_links"] = NavLinks.objects.filter(is_active=True)
            return context
```

You can inherit this view in other views so you dont have to write context part in each views eg.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class IndexView(NavView, TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    # other methods and stuffs
    def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
        context =  super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        # this context has nav_links
        # other context data
        context["other"] = somedata
        return context
```

Now only thing is to show data in template so I would go with creating one nav.html file and extend that file in base.html

**nav.html**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        {% for nav_link in nav_links %}
            <li><a href="{{nav_link.address}}">{{nav_link.title}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% extends 'nav.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
 <!-- Other Main Content -->
{% endblock content %}
```

I think this should be enough for simple one level menu.